# How to make player image pause but game continues in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

I'm making a clone for flappy bird but when i want the wings to flap, they flap crazily quickly so is there a way for them to pause on one image for a couple of secondes before changing to the next? Heres my code

```
first=1
if first==1:
    playern=1
    comeback=False
    first=2
if obspeed==1 and playern==1:
    imagefile="player1"
    player=pygame.image.load(imagefile+".png")
    screen.blit(player, [x, int(y)])
    y+=3
    playern=2
    pygame.display.update()
if obspeed==1 and playern==2 and comeback==False:
    imagefile="player"
    player=pygame.image.load(imagefile+".png")
    screen.blit(player, [x, int(y)])
    y-=2
    playern=3
    pygame.display.update()
if obspeed==1 and playern==3:
    imagefile="player3"
    player=pygame.image.load(imagefile+".png")
    screen.blit(player, [x, int(y)])
    y-=3
    playern=2
    comeback=True
    pygame.display.update()
if obspeed==1 and playern==2 and comeback==True:
    imagefile="player"
    player=pygame.image.load(imagefile+".png")
    screen.blit(player, [x, int(y)])
    y+=2
    playern=1
    comeback=False
    pygame.display.update()
if obspeed==0:
    imagefile="player2"
    player=pygame.image.load(imagefile+".png")
    screen.blit(player, [x, int(y)])`
```

Comment: If you found a solution for your problem, please consider posting your own answer to help future visitors facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should start by setting the framerate limit like this:

```
FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

and then at the very end of main loop put:

```
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Also you don't need to call pygame.displayupdate() in every conditional statement, you know the game loop gets executed 60 times every second, if you set the limit to 60, so its fast enough to update everything that's going on in your loop.

I recommend you reading this:
http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapters/

that online book explains really well how to use pygame
I hope this helps you :)

Comment: that doesn't help, but thx for trying. I resolved the issue i just made the bird change image every time the pipe decreased its xlocation by 10